# Detect the indentation style of a source file

Tags: python, metaprogramming, indentation

I'm writing a tool which has to do with injecting code into Python code and recompiling it.

I need to be able to detect whether a given source file (or function within it) uses spaces or tabs as the indentation symbol. Is there an easy way to do so?

Comment: Did you looked at [tabnanny](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/tabnanny.py) ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try parsing the document by newline without trimming and then checking if each line start with space or tab and then exit as soon as either one is detected? For example:

```
re.match(' ', line): -> space
re.match('\t', line): -> tab
```

Alternatively, you could use [startwith()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_startswith.htm) method - run it in a loop and exit as soon as you detect either a tab or space at the beginning of line:

```
' foo'.startswith(('\s'))
True
'   foo'.startswith(('\t'))
True
```

One thing I see as a potential problem is if the file uses tabs, but somebody pressed space before putting in a comment (#) - but I imagine detecting comments and ignoring those should not be difficult.

Comment: `re.match(r'\s', line)` actually matches on tabs, too. Just write spaces as literal spaces `' '` and tabs either as literal tabs `' '` or as '\t' (not `r'\t'`).